# iOS IB Storyboard: Navigation Bar doesn't show in some child views

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

See the image below. I've Tab Bar Controller. I've embedded Table view in Navigation Controller. I've further child Table view & two UI views. 
As you can see Navigation Bar appears for some view while it doesn't appear for other. Why is this? How to fix it.
I've not added any code, just trying it in storyboard.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a Navigation item from the object library to the nav bar? It might give you the title you want to see.

Comment: These child views are already embedded in a Navigation View so we shouldn't be adding any additional Navigation Bar which defeats the whole purpose of embedding views in a Navigation Controller. Mark's answer below is what sorted it out.

Comment: I never mentioned an additional navigation bar. I mentioned a navigation item. Your nav bar was already visible, but it seemed the title was not. In the past i had needed to add a navigation item myself to show a title in storyboard. In case it was a similiar issue i left a comment. Was just trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is showing the navigation bar just not the title of the other view controllers. That's where you are seeing `<Back`. If you set the Title field on the view controller, you should see the title in that same area.

Comment: Thanks Mark, Setting the title in child views solved the issue.